# Where's the line between an answer and spam?

Tags: discussion

This answer is mostly an answer and then at the end it promotes what seems to be the answerer's web site:

https://music.stackexchange.com/a/71542/6070

The web site name matches the user name, so it's not like the affiliation is hidden, but it's also not explicitly disclosed. It feels like spam to me, but I'm reluctant to be too strict about it all on my own. Hence this question. Is this spam?

Comment: If the answer is legit, just edit and remove the spammy part (especially if it's unrelated to the question) and perhaps also leave a comment about [how to not be a spammer](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/promotion)

Comment: It should be noted that this user had another answer posted around the same time that included the same website link. That post deleted by now.