# Are these answers spam masquerading as good answers?

Tags: support, flagging

A new user has posted 8 answers (so far) clearly aimed at driving traffic to a particular website. The answers themselves don't raise flags with me (downvotes, maybe), and even the website reference wouldn't, except that it's eight answers in a short time.

There's no disclosure of affiliation.

Flag all of them? Flag one with note to mod about the others? Downvote? Ignore? Open a Meta discussion?

---

**Update:** I've left a comment on each of them.

> Hi Steve van Christie. Welcome to Music Practice and Theory. As an FYI, answers like this, that seem geared toward driving traffic to a website, need to disclose your affiliation. Otherwise they may be considered spam and deleted.

**Update 2:** OP replied to each comment that he is the creator.

> im creator of that site (music tools to help or test or clarificaty my answer if the others want to check or clarified it), if it's not allowed, then i'll edited the answer without the answer

---

- [Difference between keys and scales?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3019/wheres-the-line-between-an-answer-and-spam)
- [Does it really make difference to play a song in a different key?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/3486/does-it-really-make-difference-to-play-a-song-in-a-different-key)
- [Relative minor: What notes do I actually play?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/108690/relative-minor-what-notes-do-i-actually-play)
- [can someone help me make sense of guitar inversions](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/107843/can-someone-help-me-make-sense-of-guitar-inversions)
- [Is there a reason why “Scale Inversions” don't get discussed?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/107461/is-there-a-reason-why-scale-inversions-dont-get-discussed)
- [Beginner Confusion Over Guitar Scales](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/108742/beginner-confusion-over-guitar-scales)
- [What tuning would I use if the song is in E but I want to use G shapes?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/108323/what-tuning-would-i-use-if-the-song-is-in-e-but-i-want-to-use-g-shapes)
- [Can any song on guitar be played with standard tuning and without a capo?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/96125/can-any-song-on-guitar-be-played-with-standard-tuning-and-without-a-capo)

---

Related to: [Where's the line between an answer and spam?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3019/wheres-the-line-between-an-answer-and-spam)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You did the right thing by flagging, but additionally raising the list in here made it much easier for me to go through them in a block. Otherwise different mods may have dealt with different ones, and the overall picture may not have been clear.

As the majority of their posts were low quality, I deleted them, and I edited the remaining ones to remove the spam link, while letting them know they can put the link in their profile.

As I'm in the UK, I was asleep when you did the original flagging, otherwise I would have got to them faster :-)

Comment: Good to know the Meta post can be helpful in a case like this. Credit where credit's due dept.: Flags must have been raised by someone else.